# Is it possible to consciously increase or decrease your own heart beat?

Tags: cardiology, human-physiology, health, fitness, biofeedback

By doing yoga, can we manipulate our own heart beat? Is that possible for humans?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Health SE, Fitness SE, or Hinduism SE.

Comment: @AMR please don't vote for migration because questions are "better suited" elsewhere. They should only be migrated if they are actually off-topic on the site they were posted at. Is it off-topic for Biology.SE? It's also likely not on-topic on Health.SE https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @YviDe I tend to agree with Werner's comments on the answer to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/298921 The phenomenon can occur, but I do not know that we can say from an evidence based biological perspective why or how. If the question has a better home somewhere else, which in this case it does, then it should be moved.  There are 0 questions and 2 answers for yoga on Bio, 5Q & 10A on Health, 437 results on PhysFit, and 382 results on Hinduism. Another thing is that it is also likely a duplicate question on those sites and will be addressed accordingly. Clearly not Bio.

Comment: You can change your heartbeat even by running or doing any form of exercise. You have to add more details to make this question on-topic in Biology.SE

Comment: Getting startled is a function of expectation vs.result, mentally. You can "psych yourself up" to become more likely to startle. Arousal is another case where entirely internal thoughts can trigger the state. In both cases, the body will increase heart rate. Calming yourself or angering yourself will affect rate, too. There are things that can be consciously done to affect our heart rate, even entirely mentally. If you want to ask something more specific, I recommend clarifying that point better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can decrease your own heart rate very simply by stimulating the vagus nerve in what are called 'vagal maneuvers'. If you stick your thumb in your mouth, wrap your lips tightly around your thumb, and blow on your thumb like you are blowing up a balloon, you will stimulate the vagus nerve and decrease HR. This technique is often used clinically, and is termed the 'valsalva maneuver'. The vagus nerve runs posterior to the oropharynx. Blowing on the thumb increases pressure in the chest cavity and stimulates a **parasympathetic response**. Another technique is **carotid sinus massage**, which works in a similar way, by modulating vagal tone. Many other techniques exist. Another is the result of the **'mammalian diving reflex'**, which slows heart rate in response to immersing the face in cold water.

[image: The Autonomic Nervous System]

**Vagal maneuvers** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagal_maneuver

**Carotid sinus** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carotid_sinus

**Carotid sinus massage** http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3985038

http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/carotid+sinus+massage

**Vagus nerve** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagus_nerve

**Valsalva maneuver (see section on heart, where tachycardia means high heart rate)** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valsalva_maneuver

**WebMD on decreasing HR** http://www.webmd.com/heart-disease/atrial-fibrillation/tc/vagal-maneuvers-for-a-fast-heart-rate-topic-overview

Comment: You can do that with autogenic training too, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogenic_training - without blowing the thumb.

Comment: Ott, you actually should post that as an answer, since that actually is the answer to the intended question. (I'm pretty darn sure)